# is there any tool to merge different swagger json files to one

Tags: json, merge, yaml, swagger

i want to merge two or more swagger files to one by giving their local paths
I have tried swagger-merger but didnt work
any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO! Questions seeking tool recommendations are off-topic on this site, you could instead edit your question and provide details of your problems with *swagger-merger* so people can help you with that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.